# Defining multiple plots to be animated with a for loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

[Thanks to Jake Vanderplas](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), I know how to start to code an animated plot with [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/). Here is a sample code:

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(0, 100))

line, = plt.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data([0, 2], [0,i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Suppose now I'd like to plot tons of functions (say four here), defined with the help of a loop. I did some voodoo programming, trying to understand how to mimic the comma following line and here is what I got (needless to say that it does not work: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'axes'`).

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(0, 100))

line = []
N = 4

for j in range(N):
    temp, = plt.plot([], [])
    line.append(temp)

line = tuple(line)

def init():
    for j in range(N):
        line[j].set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    for j in range(N):
        line[j].set_data([0, 2], [10 * j,i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

**Some my question is:** how can I make it work? Bonus (probably linked): what is the difference between `line, = plt.plot([], [])` and `line = plt.plot([], [])`?

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the solution below I showcase a bigger example (with also **bar plot**) that may help people understand better what should be done for other cases. After the code I explain some details and answer the bonus question.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg') #use Qt5 as backend, comment this line for default backend

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(0, 100))

N = 4
lines = [plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)] #lines to animate

rectangles = plt.bar([0.5,1,1.5],[50,40,90],width=0.1) #rectangles to animate

patches = lines + list(rectangles) #things to animate

def init():
    #init lines
    for line in lines:
        line.set_data([], [])

    #init rectangles
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        rectangle.set_height(0)

    return patches #return everything that must be updated

def animate(i):
    #animate lines
    for j,line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_data([0, 2], [10 * j,i])

    #animate rectangles
    for j,rectangle in enumerate(rectangles):
        rectangle.set_height(i/(j+1))

    return patches #return everything that must be updated

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

### Explanation

The idea is to plot what you need and then reuse the artists (see more [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html)) returned by `matplotlib`. This is done by first plotting a dummy sketch of what you want and keeping the objects `matplotlib` gives you. Then on your `init` and `animate` functions you can update the objects that need to be animated.

Note that in `plt.plot([], [])[0]` we get a single **line artist**, thus I collect them with `[plt.plot([], [])[0] for _ in range(N)]`. On the other hand `plt.bar([0.5,1,1.5],[50,40,90],width=0.1)` returns a container that can be iterated for the **rectangle artists**. `list(rectangles)` just convert this container into a list to be concatenated with `lines`.

I separate the lines from the rectangles because they are updated differently (and are different artists) but `init` and `animate` return all of them.

**Answer to bonus question:**

1. `line, = plt.plot([], [])` assign the first element of the list returned by `plt.plot` to the veriable `line`.
2. `line = plt.plot([], [])` just assign the whole list (of only one element).

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask "what" is the first element of `plt.plot` list?

Comment: `plt.plot` returns a list of `matplotlib.artist.Artist`s, so when you plot only one line it returns a list of only one item: a `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` artist. But if you plot several lines as in `lines = plt.plot( *([[], []]*N) )` it returns all the lines on a list.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. Is the comma after `line` in the `return` of `animate` is not mandatory? If I understand correctly your solution, there is no such comma.

Comment: There is not comma but check that I do this `plt.plot([], [])[0]` to get the first value. The `line, = plt.plot([], [])` syntax is to make this line `line = plt.plot([], [])[0]` more concise using the unpacking feature of python assignment like on `a,b = [1,2]`

Comment: Thanks. See my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21953846/1195799).

Comment: Hi, can I ask a question to extend this? In your example you have multiple `lines` objects, however what happens if I want to update a `lines` and `image` object (like update the position of a point and update a `matshow()` array in the animation. Could I put those two in the same tuple?

Comment: What if I don't want to use plt.plot, but e.g. plt.bar ? And maybe, I want to plot several lines, not just one.

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon and Sören, I expanded the example. I hope it answers your doubts. Still if you need more specific clarifications you can always ask a new question ;)

Comment: If I comment out the parts related to rectangles, I get only one line. Why is this so?
I've been trying to use matplotlib.. but when using Anaconda, there seems to be some truly unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified example which is more readable.
This is just the code from the matplotlib website with another piece added. What threw me was I wasn't initially realizing the plt functions were returning lists, overlooking the trailing comma, or even how things were being tied together, which seems to be getting handled pretty implicitly by the library itself. But the key is to create several update-able objects and return them from the two key functions as part of the same list and they will be synced when the animation is run.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
xdata2,ydata2= [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro') 
ln2, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro')

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return ln,ln2

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    xdata2.append(frame)
    ydata2.append(np.cos(frame))
    ln2.set_data(xdata2,ydata2)
    
    return ln,ln2

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)


plt.show()
```

For more fun change the animation callback to the following:

```
def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame)
    ydata.append(np.sin(frame))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    delta = 2*np.pi/128
    xdata2.append([frame*2,frame*2+delta])
    ydata2.append([np.cos(frame*2), np.cos(frame*2+delta)])
    ln2.set_data(xdata2,ydata2)
    
    return ln,ln2
```