# Difference between `return line, ` and `return line`

Tags: python, matplotlib

In [a recent question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21937976/1195799), I quote some code by [Jake Vanderplas](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/). One can find the following code:

```python
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(0, 100))

line, = plt.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data([0, 2], [0,i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

In the `init` or `animate`function, the return "value" is `line,` (with a comma).

**Question:** Is there a difference with a return "value" that would be `line` (whitout comma)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`line,` is a tuple with one object in it.
`line` is just the line object.

```
In [80]: line = object()

In [81]: line,
Out[81]: (<object at 0x9ee7fa8>,)
```

Comment: ... and a lot of people will write `(line,)` to generate that tuple even in contexts where the parentheses are redundant. It's pretty easy to overlook the comma without them. Although I suppose if we weren't helping each other out by supplying the parens then we'd get better at spotting the comma :-)

Comment: Thanks. What's the advantage in that context of a tuple with one element ?

Comment: @cjorssen: `init` and `animate` return tuples here to honor the specs for `FuncAnimation`. [The docs say](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation), "If blit=True, func and init_func should return an **iterable** of drawables to clear."

Comment: Many thanks. So a tuple is not mandatory. One could return a list (it is an iterable IIUC) of one element?