# Add new bins at each iteration of a bar plot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, bar-chart

I'm [slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21937976/1195799) [learning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21953846/1195799) how to animate figures with [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/). Now, I have a bar plot, and I'd like to add a new bin every new frame (and adapt the width and height of the others).

Here is what I've done so far.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

N = 10

plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)

x = np.arange(N)
y = np.zeros(N)

bars = plt.bar(x,y,1)

for bar in bars:
    ax.add_patch(bar)

def init():
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_height(0.)
    return [bar for bar in bars]

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    for j, bar in enumerate(bars):
        bar.set_height(j+i)
        bar.set_width(bar.get_width()/float(i+1))
    return [bar for bar in bars]

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames = 10, interval=200, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

So, in the code above, `animate` should add a new bar for every `i` in [1;10], starting with 10 bars, then 11, ... , and finally 20.

**Question:** How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

N = 10
M = 10

plt.xlim(0,N+M)
plt.ylim(0,N+M)

x = np.arange(N+M)
y = np.arange(N+M)

bars = [b for b in plt.bar(x[:N],y[:N],1)]

def init():
    return bars

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    if i<M:
        bars.append(plt.bar(x[N+i],y[N+i],1)[0]) 
    return bars
    
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames = 10, interval=200, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]