# Defining multiple plot objects in an array and updating in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I followed the answer to the following question

[Defining multiple plots to be animated with a for loop in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937976/defining-multiple-plots-to-be-animated-with-a-for-loop-in-matplotlib)

The answer defines and plots the lines, but I want to plot and update the points in the animation. I modified the code and am trying to plot the points. When I run the code it is showing blank figure, plotting nothing.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(0, 100))

N = 4
points = ax.plot( *([[], []]*N) )

def init():    
    for line in points:
        line.set_data([], [])
    return points

def animate(i):
    # for j,line in enumerate(lines):
    #   print j,i
    #     line.set_data([0,j], [2,i])
    points[0].set_data([[0],[i]])
    points[1].set_data([[1],[i+1]])
    points[2].set_data([[2],[i+2]])
    points[3].set_data([[3],[i+3]])
    return points

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`set_data()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_data) function needs a list of at least 2 elements as it draws a line.

For Example:

```
def animate(i):
    points[0].set_data([[0, 1],[i, i+1]])
    points[1].set_data([[1, 2],[i+1, i+2]])
    points[2].set_data([[2, 3],[i+2, i+3]])
    points[3].set_data([[3, 4],[i+3, i+4]])
    return points
```

It is only necessary to make the points visible, for that we place a marker:

```
points = ax.plot( *([[], []]*N), marker="o")
```

Complete Code:

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(0, 100))

N = 4
points = ax.plot( *([[], []]*N), marker="o")

def init():    
    for line in points:
        line.set_data([], [])
    return points

def animate(i):
    points[0].set_data([0],[i])
    points[1].set_data([[1],[i+1]])
    points[2].set_data([[2],[i+2]])
    points[3].set_data([[3],[i+3]])
    return points

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is true, but I want to plot and update points, not lines. Could you please tell me what modifications do I have to make to the code to plot points.

Comment: Look at my answer, update it with your requirements. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark as correct please.