# Matplotlib's FuncAnimation calls init_func more than once

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The documentation for `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` says:

> **init_func** : [...]  This function will be called once before the first frame.

But whenever I use `FuncAnimation`, the `init_func` is called multiple times.
You can see this by adding a print statement to the [basic example from Matplotlib's website](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_anim.html):

```
"""
A simple example of an animated plot
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))


def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,


# Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():

    # ---> Adding a print statement here <---
    print('Initializing')  

    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init,
                              interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Apart from producing a lovely plot, it immediately gives the standard output:

```
Initializing
Initializing
```

If I keep the animation running, the `init_func` is in fact called over and over again!
Is this a bug or a feature? What can I do about it?

---

A little background: I use the `init_func` to initialize multiple plots [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21938297/4743630), only within a class:

```
class MyAnimation:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.n = n
        self.lines = []

    def run_animation(self):
        def init():
            for i in range(self.n):
                line = ax.plot([], [])[0]
                self.lines.append(line)     
            return self.lines

        def animate(i):
            ... # Update lines
            return self.lines

        animation = FuncAnimation(self.fig, animate, init_func=init, blit=True)
        plt.show()
```

Of course, this makes no sense if `init()` is called more than once, because additional lines will be appended to `self.lines`.
Is my approach not good practice?
Should I set `self.lines = []` inside the `init()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it should be mentionned that "This function will be called once before the first frame." means that it is called once before the first frame *per animation*. So because the `FuncAnimation`'s `repeat` argument is `True` by default, each time the animation is repeated, `init_func` will be called again.

Next you are right that this function is actually called twice. The first call is to set the animation up. This step is apparently needed internally. One therefore should take this into account and make sure the init function does not produce anything irreversible in the plot.
Also note that if you did not provide any init_func, the first frame would be used for the internal setup procedure.

Therefore I think you are completely right to reset the `lines` attribute in the `init_func`. Possibly you might even want to clear the axes (`self.ax.clear()`) to get rid of previously drawn elements.

Comment: Yuck, I hoped I could later do something like `ani = MyAnimation()`, then change the layout e.g. with `ani.fig.set_facecolor('blue')` before I call `ani.run_animation()`. That won't be possible when I clear the axes in the `init_func`...

Comment: Correct. In that case you may iterate over the lines and remove them, e.g. `for line in self.lines: line.remove()`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest For me when I put `init_func=plt.cla` then I am seeing the effect only on the first frame of the whole animation  (includig the repeats).