# Animating two subfigures with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create animation of histogram and a plot together, side-by-side. I learned how to make histogram from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animated_histogram.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-animated-histogram-py) and to do multiple plotting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937976/defining-multiple-plots-to-be-animated-with-a-for-loop-in-matplotlib).

When I tried to combine the codes together as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n_frames = 100 #total number of frames
time = [] #x-axis data
mean = [] #y-axis data

def animate(frame_number, bar_container, line):
        data = np.random.randn(1000) #generate data

        n, _ = np.histogram(data, HIST_BINS) #create histogram

        for count, rect in zip(n, bar_container.patches):
            rect.set_height(count)

        time.append(frame_number)#update x-axis
        mean.append(np.mean(data))#update y-axis

        line.set_data(time, mean)

        return bar_container.patches, line

HIST_BINS = np.linspace(-4, 4, 100)
data = np.random.randn(1000)
n, _ = np.histogram(data, HIST_BINS)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.set_ylim(top=55)  # set safe limit to ensure that all data is visible.
ax1.set_ylabel('Count')
ax1.set_xlabel('Lengths')

_, _, bar_container = ax1.hist(data, HIST_BINS, lw=1, ec="yellow", fc="green", alpha=0.5)

line, = ax2.plot([], [])
ax2.set_ylim(-4,4)
ax2.set_xlim(0, n_frames)
ax2.set_ylabel('mean')
ax2.set_xlabel('time')

fig.tight_layout(pad = 1)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = np.arange(n_frames), fargs = (bar_container,line), blit=True)
plt.show()
```

The code process 1st frame and then stops with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 975, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1719, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1748, in _draw_frame
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
  File "/home/kartik/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1748, in <lambda>
    key=lambda x: x.get_zorder())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_zorder'
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I resolve it?

Thanks