# animated multi-subplot with matplotlib hist

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, matplotlib-animation

I try to adapt this code [animated plot line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832055/animated-subplots-using-matplotlib) to similar situation but using hist in lieu of line plot and expend it to 4 subplot. It seem to be an easy task with this great exemple but I struggle an error on the adaptation.

```
line1, = ax1.hist([], HIST_BINS1, lw=1, density=True, color='orange', alpha=0.5, 
label='1 an')
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

I try to remove the "comma" but don't seem to be the solution, thank to all one who will take time to check my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from typing import Generator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

path = "E:/data/HQ/meteo_app_moy/"
file = "Rouge (040204)_1062.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(path + file, usecols=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], sep=";", header=None,         
                  decimal=",", thousands=".")
data['date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1950', end='31/12/2021')
data = data.set_index('date')
yrs = list(data.index.year.unique())
HIST_BINS1 = np.linspace(data[3].min(), data[3].max(), round(data[3].max() / 2))
HIST_BINS2 = np.linspace(data[4].min(), data[4].max(), round(data[4].max() / 2))
HIST_BINS3 = np.linspace(-40, 40, 40)
HIST_BINS4 = np.linspace(0, data[0].max(), 100)


def data_gen():
    cnt = 0
    while cnt <= len(yrs):
        cnt += 1
        y1 = data.iloc[data.index.year.isin([yrs[cnt]]), 3]  # pluie
        y1 = y1[y1 > 0]
        y2 = data.iloc[data.index.year.isin([yrs[cnt]]), 4]  # neige
        y2 = y2[y2 > 1]
        y3 = data[[1, 2]].mean(axis=1)  # Tmoy
        y3 = y3.iloc[y3.index.year.isin([yrs[cnt]])]
        y4 = data.iloc[data.index.year.isin([yrs[cnt]]), 0]  # App
        yield y1, y2, y3, y4


# create a figure with two subplots
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

# add a fixed hist as ref
ax1.hist(data.loc[data[3]>1,3], HIST_BINS1, lw=1, density=True, color='steelblue',         
           alpha=0.5, label='histo')
# intialize hist objects (one in each axes)
line1, = ax1.hist([], HIST_BINS1, lw=1, density=True, color='orange', alpha=0.5,         
                  label='1 an')
line2, = ax2.hist([], HIST_BINS2, lw=1, density=True)
line3, = ax3.hist([], HIST_BINS3, lw=1, density=True)
line4, = ax4.hist([], HIST_BINS4, lw=1, density=True)
line = [line1, line2, line3, line4]

# initialize the data arrays
y1data, y2data, y3data, y4data = [], [], [], []


def run(data):
    # update the data
    y1, y2, y3, y4 = data
    # xdata.append(t)
    y1data.append(y1)
    y2data.append(y2)
    y3data.append(y3)
    y4data.append(y4)

    # update the data of both line objects
    line[0].set_data(y1data)
    line[1].set_data(y2data)
    line[2].set_data(y3data)
    line[3].set_data(y4data)
    return line


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, blit=True, interval=2,
                          repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

PS: sorry for my english Im working hard on it

Comment: Did you look into [this animated histogram from the tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/animated_histogram.html)? And into [Defining multiple plots to be animated with a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937976/defining-multiple-plots-to-be-animated-with-a-for-loop-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: yes but when I try to merge all go wrong